# Laravel Relationships vs. Runtime -> how to reduce amount of databse queries

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship, laravel-5

I really love it how laravel handels relationships with just some lines of code. But when there is a huge amount of data it's slowing down by making to many requests to the database.

```
class Object extends Model {
    public function users() {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class);
    }
}

class User extends Model {
   proteced $appends = [
       'url'
   ];

   public function object() {
       return $this->belongsTo(Object::class);
   }

   public function getUrlAttribute() {
       return 'exmaple.com/object/' . $this->object->value . '/user/' . $this->id;
   }
}
```

When I call

```
return Object::with('users')->find(2);
```

it will make always a new query to the database for the url generation.

So is there a clean way to reduce the amount of queries so I can speed up the application?

Comment: You can use cache, for example with this package: https://github.com/dwightwatson/rememberable. Or use `Object::with('users')->get()` to  fetch all objects and then use a foreach

Comment: I tried the normal cache function of laravel with a file but the time is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you are causing new queries because you are calling a relationship that isn't loaded on User. You could eager load more:

```
Object::with('users.object')....
```

But you could also keep going down that line infinitely because of the way these reference one another.

Perhaps that method doesn't belong on the User model if you intend on using it that way.